# How to allow users to upload an image to SQLite database in Flask?

Tags: python, database, sqlite, flask, user-input

I'm learning flask by using the [tutorial on the flask website](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/1.1.x/tutorial/) to create a basic blogging app called Flaskr. Right now I'm wanting to add functionality to allow users to upload images to the SQLite database, but I haven't found any answers that would help me implement that into my existing code.

Here's all my code minus accounts, tests, and authentication, which aren't relevant.

*flaskr/__init__.py*

```
import os
from flask import Flask

def create_app():
  # create and configure the app
  app = Flask(__name__)
  app.config.from_mapping(
    SECRET_KEY='dev',
    DATABASE=os.path.join(app.instance_path, 'flaskr.sqlite'),
  )

  # ensure the instance folder exists
  try:
    os.makedirs(app.instance_path)
  except OSError:
    pass

  # a simple page that says hello
  @app.route('/hello')
  def hello():
    return 'Hello, World!'

  from . import db
  db.init_app(app)

  from . import blog
  app.register_blueprint(blog.bp)
  app.add_url_rule('/', endpoint='index')

  return app
```

*flaskr/db.py*

```
import sqlite3

import click
from flask import current_app, g
from flask.cli import with_appcontext

def get_db():
  if 'db' not in g:
    g.db = sqlite3.connect(
      current_app.config['DATABASE'],
      detect_types=sqlite3.PARSE_DECLTYPES
    )
    g.db.row_factory = sqlite3.Row

  return g.db

def close_db(e=None):
  db = g.pop('db', None)

  if db is not None:
    db.close()

def init_db():
  db = get_db()

  with current_app.open_resource('schema.sql') as f:
    db.executescript(f.read().decode('utf8'))

@click.command('init-db')
@with_appcontext
def init_db_command():
  init_db()
  click.echo('Initialized the database.')

def init_app(app):
  app.teardown_appcontext(close_db)
  app.cli.add_command(init_db_command)
```

*flaskr/schema.sql*

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS post;

CREATE TABLE post (
  id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,
  created TIMESTAMP NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  title TEXT NOT NULL,
  body TEXT NOT NULL,
);
```

*flaskr/blog.py*

```
from flask import (
    Blueprint, flash, g, redirect, render_template, request, url_for
)
from werkzeug.exceptions import abort

from flaskr.db import get_db

bp = Blueprint('blog', __name__)

@bp.route('/')
def index():
    db = get_db()
    posts = db.execute(
      'SELECT p.id, title, body, created'
      ' FROM post p'
      ' ORDER BY created DESC'
    ).fetchall()
    return render_template('blog/index.html', posts=posts)

@bp.route('/create', methods=('GET', 'POST'))
def create():
    if request.method == 'POST':
        title = request.form['title']
        body = request.form['body']
        error = None

        if not title:
            error = 'Title is required.'

        if error is not None:
            flash(error)
        else:
            db = get_db()
            db.execute(
                'INSERT INTO post (title, body)'
                ' VALUES (?, ?)',
                (title, body)
            )
            db.commit()
            return redirect(url_for('blog.index'))

    return render_template('blog/create.html')
```

*flaskr/templates/base.html*

```
<!doctype html>
<title>{% block title %}{% endblock %} - Flaskr</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ url_for('static', filename='style.css') }}">

<h1>Flaskr</h1>

<section class="content">
  <header>
    {% block header %}{% endblock %}
  </header>
  {% for message in get_flashed_messages() %}
    <div class="flash">{{ message }}</div>
  {% endfor %}
  {% block content %}{% endblock %}
</section>
```

*flaskr/templates/blog/index.html*

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}

{% block header %}
  <h1>{% block title %}Posts{% endblock %}</h1>
  <a class="action" href="{{ url_for('blog.create') }}">New</a>
{% endblock %}

{% block content %}
  {% for post in posts %}
    <article class="post">
      <header>
        <div>
          <h1>{{ post['title'] }}</h1>
          <div class="about">{{ post['created'].strftime('%Y-%m-%d') }}</div>
        </div>
      </header>
      <p class="body">{{ post['body'] }}</p>
    </article>
    {% if not loop.last %}
      <hr>
    {% endif %}
  {% endfor %}
{% endblock %}
```

*flaskr/templates/blog/create.html*

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}

{% block header %}
  <h1>{% block title %}New Post{% endblock %}</h1>
{% endblock %}

{% block content %}
  <form method="post">
    <label for="title">Title</label>
    <input name="title" id="title" value="{{ request.form['title'] }}" required>
    <label for="body">Body</label>
    <textarea name="body" id="body">{{ request.form['body'] }}</textarea>
    <input type="submit" value="Save">
  </form>
{% endblock %}
```

You can find the code in its entirety [here.](https://replit.com/@MICAHSPENCE/flasktutorial)

Comment: is this helpful?  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51779568/how-do-i-store-a-picture-in-a-table-with-python-sqlite3 . once you know how to save from python then code can be exported to flask too.